# How to get the position of an Item from a PopupMenu in a custom ListView

Tags: android, xml, listview, popupmenu

Here's the problem: I've got a custom ArrayAdapter (overriden getView). Each item has got

- 2 ImageView
- 2 EditText

One of those ImageView is clickable and enables a PopupMenu, so I've got a little PopupMenu for each item of the list. Now, for that menu I need some parameters from the item to wich is anchored. So, how to pass informations (like position) to the method called from the PopupMenu voice? Attached the xml files.

**item_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/firstLine"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:maxHeight="60dp"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:contentDescription="TODO"
            android:onClick="showMenu"
            android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_moreoverflow_normal_holo_light" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/secondLine"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="26dip"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/firstLine"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Author"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**menu_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

        <item
            android:id="@+id/preview"
            android:onClick="preview"
            android:title="@string/preview"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/download"
            android:onClick="download"
            android:title="@string/download"/>

    </menu>
```

**CustomArrayAdapter.java**

```
public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Custom>{

    private final Context context;
    private final List<Custom> values;
    private final int resource;
    private final ImageCache imgCache = new ImageCache();

    public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Custom> values) {
        super(context, resource, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
        this.resource = resource;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder vh;
        Custom Custom = values.get(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            vh = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
            vh.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.firstLine);
            vh.author = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.secondLine);
            vh.albumImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            convertView.setTag(vh);
        }
        else {
            vh = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        vh.requestedCustom = Custom;
        vh.title.setText(Custom.getTitle());
        vh.author.setText(Custom.getAuthor());
        String imgUrl = Custom.getImgUrl();
        if (imgUrl != null) {
            imgCache.getImage(Custom, vh);
        }
        else {
            vh.albumImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_album);
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    // This is a ViewHolder that helps in the view recycling
    public static class ViewHolder {
        public Custom requestedCustom;
        public TextView title;
        public TextView author;
        public ImageView albumImage;
    }
}
```

"preview" and "download" methods need parameters from the associated list item and I don't know how to get them. Thanks again.

**EDIT 1**

It seems that a Contextual Menu should be used instead (right?) but I would like to anchor it to each item as a sort of popup menu that appears. So how can I achieve this?
For those who don't understand what I want (due to my worst english): Google Play app, popup menu that let you choose between "Install" or "Add to whishlist".

Comment: It all depends on how you build your views. We really need the adapter code and any View class that you may have defined. If you use any bus, please also let us know (default is no).

Comment: And how do you manage the click on the image view ? I couldn't see any listener ? Nothing yet ?

Comment: @Snicolas there's an onClick tag in menu_item.xml... so there are two methods in another activity where those methods are declared. The problem is that they actually do nothing because I don't know how to get some parameters from the item where the popupMenu is anchored.

Answer (score 8):

You can create your listener class like this:

```
class myClickListener implements OnClickListener, OnMenuItemClickListener {

        long id;

        public myClickListener(long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(appContext, v);
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
            MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_item, popup.getMenu());
            popup.show();
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem arg0) {
            Toast.makeText(appContext, "ID of selected row : " + id , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }

    }
```

and add this listener to your imageview at your override getView method of adapter class:

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new myClickListener(getItemId(position)));
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply we need to set buttons tag as its position, and onClick on the PopupButton you need to get the view:

```
button.setTag(position);  //may be you can call this on getview method of list view
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int position = (Integer) v.getTag();   // you will get the position

    }
});
```

or use Interface in your fragment implements `View.OnClickListener`

```
private void showPopupMenu(View view) {

    final   int position = (Integer) view.getTag();

        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getActivity(), view);

        // Inflate our menu resource into the PopupMenu's Menu
        popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup, popup.getMenu());

        // Set a listener so we are notified if a menu item is clicked
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.menu_remove:


                System.out.println(position);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        // Finally show the PopupMenu
        popup.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to achieve what you want with a onClick declared by XML. The easiest way to solve it with your actual implementation is to :

- add a real click listener to your ImageView after inflating it. Inside your adapter.
- the listener should be a custom class implementing the OnClickListener interface
- you should also give your listener an additional data member : the position (row) that contains the ImageView.
- when the listener is activated, it will have to invoke a callback on the activity that will display the Dialog, the listener will then pass the position.

Comment: is there an alternative (easier and better) implementation? Have you seen the latest version of Google Play? There's the listView with all the apps and a popupMenu for each item of the list. The menu options are "install" or "add to wishlist". How can I achieve that?

Comment: There are easier solutions, but they involve using a bus. The way I described is not so hard, less hard than getting familiar with a bus.

Comment: a bus? is that an acronym?

Comment: No, it's a well known design pattern. Android oriented implementations include EventBus, Otto or RoboGuice.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. By the way, from the "Menus" Android documentation: **Actions in a popup menu should not directly affect the corresponding content—that's what contextual actions are for**. Maybe should I use contextual menus instead of doing what you've suggested?

Comment: Indeed, it's more or less the same. The only difference is what you do when a users clicks on an item. Displaying a full activity can be a choice, or a dialog, or a theme-dialog activity, or a simple menu. A functionally-equal option is to use split action bars with a selection mode (see gmail or gallery), but this option is quite different from others.

Comment: Can you write an example if possible?

Comment: Too many options here. Try it by yourself, and if you are blocked, then ask a new question. That's the way StackOverFlow works...

Comment: what is meant by invoking a callback on the activity? How do I go to the activity from the listener?

Comment: @user3213348 if listener is in an inner class of an view, use view.getContext for instance.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  But I am confused by Inner class of view?  I have a custom adapter and a separate custom listener class.  Inside the adapters getView method I add the listener. I m trying to change the listview based on the pop menu like delete n update my sqlite db.

Comment: Not an inner class of the view but of the adapter.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it:

1. Instead of storing a ViewHolder in the tags of convertView in **CustomArrayAdapter**'s **getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)** method, I stored the Custom object itself. I didn't even use a holder.

   ```
   convertView.setTag(getItem(position));
   ```

   (if you really need to store the ViewHolder, you can use setTag(int key, Object tag)
    to store multiple tags)
2. When showMenu(View view) is called by the ImageView, I use view.getParent() to get the parent LinearLayout of the currently selected view, which has my Custom object in its tag.

   ```
   View parent = (View) view.getParent();
   ```
3. Outside showMenu() I have defined a public property to store the currently selected item like this:

   ```
   public static Custom mSelectedItem;
   ```
4. Inside showMenu() I set mSelectedItem to getTag() of the parent LinearLayout from step 2.

   ```
   mSelectedItem = (Custom) parent.getTag();
   ```
5. Finally, in the **onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem)** override method I use mSelectedItem to determine the currently selected item.

   ```
   Custom custom = mSelectedItem;
   ```